# Constructing a compact set with countably infinite many limit points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I have an exercise to construct a compact set with countably infinite many limit points.

I am trying to use the set:

$$A = \{0\} \cup \{\frac{1}{n}: n=1,2,3,\ldots \}\cup \{\frac{1}{n}+ \frac{1}{m}:n=1,2,3,\ldots ; m =n+1,n+2,\ldots\}$$

The point $0$ and $\frac{1}{n}$ are clearly limit points for all $n$. I am having trouble showing that these are in fact the *only* limit points. I believe they are, and if I can show these are the only limit points it follows that $A$ is bounded and contains all its limit points therefore it is compact.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: One hazard with using this set is that $\frac1n+\frac1m$ isn't very 'nice' - they interweave with each other pretty awkwardly.  You're certainly on the right track, but consider something that will keep the sets from tangling like this - for instance, $\{\frac1{2^n}\}$ and $\{\frac1{2^n}+\frac1{2^{(n+m)}}\}$ or similar...

Comment: A possible refinement which makes the "cross contamination" easier to weed out: consider the subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\{ (0, 0) \} \cup \{ (1/n, 0) \} \cup \{ (1/n, 1/m) \}$.

Comment: (Note that my example is based on an embedding of the order $\omega^2$ into the real line; this is a handy trick to have sometimes.)

Comment: Good point - if you know general topological spaces and the properties of order topologies on ordinals, then $\omega^2 + 1 = [0, \omega^2]$ directly gives an example.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I see the advantage of using that set, but I am still having trouble with proving that the only limit points are $0$ and $\frac{1}{2^n}$.

All negative values and values beyond the upper bound clearly are not limit points. So all that is left to consider is any point $x \in A$ with $x\neq \frac{1}{2^n}$ and $0<x<\frac{1}{2}$, I am not sure how to find a neighborhood which does not intersect $A$.

Comment: @cool_guy bound $x$ between two points of the form $2^{-n}$ and $2^{-(n-1)}$; then take $2^n(x-2^{-n})$ (which will be between 0 and 1) and bound it between $2^{-m}$ and $2^{-(m-1)}$.

Comment: (Or, better yet, show that the only points between $2^{-n}$ and $2^{-(n-1)}$ that are limit points are the endpoints. Since there's only one sequence in the interval and there's only one accumulation point of that sequence, this should be pretty straightforward)

Answer (score 1):

Could you not simply put the indiscrete topology on a countably infinite set?

It would be trivially compact and every point is a limit point.

Comment: I believe this works. It is compact since the only open cover consists of the whole set, and the only neighborhood of a point is the entire set so it must intersect all other points of the set.

Comment: Right. Finding an example in familiar metric spaces would be more difficult as you know. My standard thing to try is to make "spokes" of sequences radiating out from the origin of $\mathhb{R}^2$ to countably many points on the unit circle.

Comment: Then again, maintaining compactness would be difficult in that case. Never mind.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to construct a compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb{R}$ that
contains countably infinite many limit points?

Sketch of construction: For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $\delta_{n}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})$
and let 
$$
A_{n}=\{\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{\delta_{n}}{k}\mid k\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n+1}\}.
$$
Finally, define $K=\{0\}\cup\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}$.
It can be verified that $K$ is compact and the set of limit points
of $K$ is precisely $\{0\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n+1}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

(I). Exercise: $\{0\}\cup \{1/m: M\in \Bbb N\}$ is a  closed set.

(II).For $n\in \Bbb N$ let $S(n)=\{1/n+x: x=0 \lor n\leq 1/x\in \Bbb N \}.$   Let $B= \{0\}\cup (\;\cup_{n\in \Bbb N}S(n)\;).$

Obviously $\{0\}\cup \{1/n:n\in \Bbb N\}\subset B\subset A$.

We also have $A\subset B.$ For if  $a\in A$ and $a\ne \{0\}\cup \{1/n:n\in \Bbb N\} $ then $a=1/U+1/V$ with $U,V\in \Bbb N .$ Then $a\in S(\min (U,V)).$.... Therefore $B=A$.

(III). Let  $(x_j)_{j\in \Bbb N}$ be a  sequence in $A$  converging to  $L.$  For $n\in \Bbb N$ let $T(n)=\{j\in \Bbb N: x_j\in S(n)\}.$

(III-1). If  $T(n)$ is finite for every $n$ then for any $r>0$ take $n_r\in \Bbb N$ such that $1/n_r<r/2.$ Then  $\{j\in \Bbb N:x_j\geq r\}$ is a subset of the finite set $\cup \{T(n):n<r_n\} $  . Therefore $L=0.$

(III-2). If $T(n_0)$ is infinite let $T(n_0)=\{f(n):n\in \Bbb N\}$ where $f:\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ is strictly increasing. Let $x_{f(n)}=1/n_0+y_n$ where $y_n=0$ or $n_0\leq 1/y_n\in \Bbb N.$ Then $L-1/n_0=\lim_{n\to \infty}y_n.$ By the Exercise, $L-1/n_0\in \{0\}\cup \{1/m:m\in \Bbb N\}.$ Therefore $L\in A.$