# Are these the limit points of the set S? Finding Limit Points of a Set

Tags: calculus, general-topology

If we have the subset $S$ of the metric space $(R^2,d_{{\infty}})$  such that $$S=\{(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m},0): n,m \in \mathbb{N}\}$$,
I have found out that the limit points of $S$, contained in the set $S'$ are: $$S'={ \left\lbrace(0,0) \right\rbrace}\cup{(\frac{1}{m},0):m\in\mathbb{N}}$$

I want to know if that is correct.

To find these limit points,

a) I fixed m, and then I got a sequence $(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m},0)=(b^{(n)})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ which converges to a point of the form $(\frac{1}{m},0)$

b) Next I shew (0,0) is also a limit point, since if we take n=m, we get a sequence $(c^{(n)})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}:(c^{(n)})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=(\frac{2}{n},0)$, which converges to $(0,0)$

Comment: This is not a complete proof.  You have demonstrated that points of that form are limit points but you have not yet proved that those are *all* of the set's limit points.

Comment: Thank you. But,are those the limit points of S?

Comment: It's not immediately obvious to me that those are all of them, and I'm afraid I don't have time right now to reach a firm conclusion.

Comment: I guess $d_\infty((x,y),(x',y')) = \max(\lvert x - x' \rvert, \lvert y - y' \rvert)$?

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3121709.

Comment: @RobertShore. Those ARE all of them.

Comment: @PaulFrost. And I think the Q in your link is a duplicate, as I dimly recall giving an answer or a long comment to it  a few years ago.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet It also happens to me that I am sure that I have seen a question before (or even that I gave an answer), but I do not always succeed to find the "first source" via a search. Sometimes this annoys me since there are certainly quite a number of unrecognized duplicates.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Probably you mean https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2448341.

Comment: @PaulFrost .Yes of course. I think we need computer assistance to sort and find all the duplicates and near-duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that the set of limit points of $S$ in $\Bbb{R}^2$ has the form $L \times \{ 0 \}$, where $L$ is the set of limit points of $A=\{ \frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n} : m,n \in \Bbb{N} \}$ in $\Bbb{R}$. This has been determined in [Find a set of limit point of $A=\{ \frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n} : m,n \in \Bbb{N} \}$ in $\Bbb{R}$ by using the following way.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3121709). It confirms that the set of limit points of $S$ is the set $S'$ in your question.